# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Christianity Stack Exchange breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5          8
Users destroyed                                   4          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                  17          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           322        496
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                6        264
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         39        301
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               40        516
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0        916
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              124      1,729
Tags merged                                       5          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             7          0
Tag synonyms created                              5          0
Questions unprotected                             2          0
Questions reopened                               35          7
Questions protected                              22         85
Questions migrated                               58          2
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁴                               17        381
Questions closed                                554        215
Question flags handled⁴                         197        201
Posts unlocked                                    1          4
Posts undeleted                                  21         32
Posts locked                                      3        120
Posts deleted⁵                                1,112        800
Posts bumped                                      0        273
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               37          0
Comments flagged                                337        880
Comments deleted⁶                             2,548      1,558
Comment flags handled                           754        463
Bounties canceled                                 2          0
Answers flagged                                 135      1,207
Answer flags handled                          1,286         56
All comments on a post moved to chat             15          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [Community, user #-1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...