# Who are the Moderators on Christianity Stack and are they Christians?

Tags: discussion

I came across an old Christianity Stack question where an answer had been removed by the Moderators. That made me wonder who the Moderators are.

My question is, who are the Moderators on Christianity Stack and are they happy for us to know what religious denominations they belong to?

Just found this interesting link: [2018: a year in moderation](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/2018-a-year-in-moderation)

Comment: I'm happy to tell you my own theological positions, but not very comfortable with that being mixed up with complaints about moderation. Moderators should STRICTLY AVOID taking moderator actions based on theological content. If there are problems with moderation those should be dealt with on their own right (and no most of us are not Catholics). I suggest you [edit] this to _either_ deal with the issue of deletions (if you think there is a just cause for concern) or ask a get to know you question (perhaps addressed to all high rep users, not just diamond moderators), but not mix both issues.

Comment: A list of the current moderators is here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators . By design, SE allows high-rep users to perform many moderator functions also. It is not hard to get an idea of the background of each moderator. Specifically, they posted statements when they ran for election. Their faith community was not stressed at election time nor should it affect their moderation dramatically.

Comment: @Caleb♦ I don’t have any issue with the old question where an answer was deleted. It happened before I joined C.Stack.  A reason was given for the removal, and I personally have no issue regarding deletions.  I mentioned it because that’s what made me ask this question.  Just curious!  I will edit out that aspect of my question.

Comment: AFAIK, from reading [2013 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2032), you don't need to be a Christian to be a mod on here because this is not a Christian site, but a Q&A site about Christianity...

Comment: @ Andrew T. Very helpful article.  Thanks.

Comment: Heh, heh; what about Brutus?

Comment: Required reading: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/30

Comment: I don't know who changed the tag to "discussion" or why the question shows up elsewhere under the tag "denomination-survey."  Whatever, I appreciate Peter Turner cheefully confessing he is a Catholic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the only Catholic moderator and I don't recall being called out for any papist bias - although I do have to rely on the English language, which sometimes doesn't convey the power of clear thought.

I've been called anti-Catholic and a heretic a few times though.

In my offense, I ran for moderator because I thought I could bring clarity to Catholic questions, but in retrospect I think the other mods have unfailingly done a good job of being objective to all viewpoints (and not just because of, or in spite of me. But mainly because they're good Christians, which means they're good people).

Comment: Love that phrase, "In my offense..." ! And, for a Catholic to be accused of being anti-Catholic and a heretic, depicts you walking a tightrope at high (spiritual) altitude. Keep your balance, now!

Comment: All you [moderators](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) do an excellent job. Not always an easy thing to maintain on a site with so much Christian diversity to say the least.

Comment: I agree with Ken Graham.

Comment: I agree with Ken Graham.  We are blessed with a good mod team.